# How to output the command execution line by line in PHP?

Tags: php, buffering, output-buffering

I am trying to generate the output of a command execution line by line through the following code.
When I run this I get the output, but instead of line by line, I get the whole buffer printed on each flush. I tried using ob_start & ob_clean but it didn't work.

```html
<?php

    //header('Content-Encoding: none;');
 //header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
 header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        set_time_limit(0);
        $handle = popen("dir", "r");

        if (ob_get_level() == 0) 
            ob_start();
 
        while(!feof($handle)) {
   $buffer = fgets($handle,4096);
            $buffer = trim(htmlspecialchars($buffer));
   echo $buffer;
   //echo str_pad('', 4096);    
   ob_flush();
            flush();
            sleep(1);
        }
        pclose($handle);
       ob_end_flush();
?>
```

On the front end I am using this code to display the output:

```html
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Ajax Streaming Test</title>
   </head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <body>
     <center><a href="#" id="test">Test Ajax Streaming</a></center>
  <pre><div id="mydiv"> </div></pre>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById('test').onclick = function() {
         xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open("GET", "new4.php", true);
   xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
          //alert(e.currentTarget.responseText);  
   document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += xhr.responseText+"<br>";
    
         }
         xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
             console.log("Complete = " + xhr.responseText);
           }
         }
         xhr.send();
   var res = xhr.responseText;
       };
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```